# Is there a way to programmatically traverse header files?

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a situation where I am using a library (collection of C++ header files only) that is 80MB in size in my project.

Now, I am only including 3 header files from that library in one of my source codes, but unfortunately each one of those header files include other header files and so on.

I would like to find a way to somehow traverse the header files starting from the 3 header files that I initially include to list all the header files that are being used.

I am trying to do so, so I can only include the necessary header files from that huge library in hope of reducing its size.

Comment: In most cases, reducing the number of header files will not reduce the size of the compiled binary. You'd have to trim down the library itself to do that.

Comment: The binary size is not an issue. my question was regarding the library itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC has the [`-M` flag](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) (and similar) to generate lists of dependencies.  I imagine other compilers have something similar.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know these things are possible, I will try it out.