# List header files or dependencies programatically in c++ or c# in Windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, header-files

Is there a way to list, in a c++ program or a c# program, all the header files used by another c++ file (either dot.h or dot.cpp) ?

I found this question: 
[Is there a way to programmically traverse header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970761/is-there-a-way-to-programmically-traverse-header-files)

Its answer seems to be exactly what I am looking for - except for the fact that I am using Windows (Visual Studio 2010).

I would like to be able to use something like the `gcc -M -MM -MF` options (to get a list of dependencies, or at least header files, preferably with absolute path).

The alternative, parsing the files to find the #include pattern, is fairly uncertain; not to mention additional tasks to properly identify the files... So if there was a tool that could actually do this, it would be perfectly wonderful.

Is there any Windows (programming) c++ or c# command, or pre-processor command, that can list all the header files, or all the dependencies, of a program/ file (header or implementation, since sometimes include directives can exist in implementation files too) ?

Comment: Do you want just one level of includes or all levels recursively? MSVC supports the -E / -P options to save the pre-processor output.  Then a little scripting will get a list of included files.

Comment: How do I invoke it ? I would like to use a code command if possible, I haven't found anything. I found how to get to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocess to a File, but it is not useful... I could use either (all levels of include would be great, even one would be great). Thank you.

Comment: From the IDE, enable /P and then compile the file.  It will make a .i file with the preprocessor output.  If you do not want to use the IDE, then look at Project -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line and copy the command line to a BAT script.  The compiler name is 'cl' and you many need to add that to the start of the command line. Remember to run the MSVCVARS.BAT (wrong name, but kinda close) script before trying to run cl directly.

Comment: Another option for you is to install the cygwin tools including gcc and then use gcc -M directly.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, I played with the processor options, I didn't even know what they meant until now. Great tools - for another time.

Comment: Link to another S.O. post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100372/good-tool-to-generate-dependency-diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have considered VCCodeModel, but had a bit of trouble with it, so I ended up parsing the c++ files - it is a work in progress, since I am still looking for their dependencies, and it is very hard to find the absolute path names based only on the #include directories.

Will change my answer if I find a better option, or if anyone suggests one.